# ipython + vim-jukit, import sys command not escaping double quotes

Tags: ipython, vim-plugin, neovim-plugin

Using neovim on windows 10 + powershell. vim-jukit plugin installed with lazy. My intention is to have a jupyter notebook-like experience thru (neo)vim

when pressing `<leader>os` to output split, first the following message appears in the nvim status line:

```
[vim-jukit] invalid version number encountered:
[]
[7, 3, 0]
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

then the following:

```
PS C:\Users\$USER\repos\jupyter_projs\py_testin
g> ipython3 -i -c "import sys;sys.path.append(\
"C:\\Users\\$USER\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\l
azy\\vim-jukit\\helpers\");import matplotlib.py
plot as plt;from matplotlib_show_wrapper import
 show_wrapper;plt.show = show_wrapper(plt.show,
 1);plt.show.__annotations__[\"save_dpi\"] = 15
0;from IPython import get_ipython;__shell = get
_ipython();__shell.run_line_magic(\"load_ext\",
 \"jukit_run\");__shell.run_line_magic(\"jukit_
init\", \"C:\\Users\\$USER\\repos\\jupyter_proj
s\\py_testing\\py_testing1.1.ipynb 2 --max_size
=20\");"
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 202
3, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]       
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for mo
re information
IPython 8.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Pytho
n. Type '?' for help.
  Cell In[1], line 1
    import sys;sys.path.append(" C:\\Users\\$US
ER\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\lazy\\vim-jukit\
\helpers\);import
                               ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detec
ted at line 1)


In [1]:
```

Basically, it looks like the `"` is not being escaped with the `\`. the first double quote before `import` starts the string, and then the double quote before the `C:` drive is closing the string.

```
ipython3 -i -c "import sys;sys.path.append(\"C:\\Users\\$USER\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\lazy\\vim-jukit\\helpers\")
```

I've read that you can't escape double quotes in some cases with cmd but not sure if that is correct or applicable to this.

I've also been digging thru the vim-jukit files and think I've found where the commands passed to ipython are located when calling `<leader>os` (`C:/Users/$USER/AppData/Local/nvim-data/lazy/vim-jukit/autoload/jukit/splits.vim`)

I think the pertinent code block in this file is:

```
    if use_ipy
        let pyfile_ws_sub = substitute(escape(expand('%:p'), '\'), ' ', '<JUKIT_WS_PH>', 'g')
        let store_png = g:jukit_hist_use_ueberzug ? ' --store_png' : ''
        let cmd = cmd
            \. "from IPython import get_ipython;"
            \. "__shell = get_ipython();"
            \. '__shell.run_line_magic("load_ext", "jukit_run");'
            \. '__shell.run_line_magic("jukit_init", "' . pyfile_ws_sub . ' '
            \. g:jukit_in_style . ' --max_size=' . g:jukit_max_size . store_png
            \. ueberzug_opt . '");'
        if !g:jukit_debug && !g:_jukit_is_windows
            let cmd = cmd . '__shell.run_line_magic("clear", "");'
        endif
    endif

    if g:_jukit_is_windows
        let cmd = shell_cmd . " -i -c \"" . substitute(cmd, '"', g:_jukit_win_escape_char . '"', 'g') . "\""
        return cmd
    else
        let cmd = shell_cmd . " -i -c '" . cmd . "'"
        return cmd
    endif
```

but I'm a bit lost with what's going on here

Is there a way to get the double quote escaped? Or am I looking for the solution in the wrong place?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Vim's `:help shellescape()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had PowerShell as default terminal for Vim (`vim.opt.shell = 'powershell.exe'`), removing this from `init.lua` solved the issue, works fine with default vim terminal.

Friedrich's suggestion to check out `shellescape()` also looks applicable, but for the time being I'm going back to defaults because it's a simple fix.